# Empty String Literal

Tags: c#, string

I have come across some code during a code-review where a old coworker has done the following:

```
const string replacement = @"";
```

This string is used in a regex expression as a replacement for what is matched. My question is what is the purpose of adding the @ literal sign to the beginning of an empty string. There should not be anything to literally interpret.

Would there be any difference in impact between: `@"";` and  `"";`?

Comment: Why not just try comparing the two in code.

Comment: There is no difference in the debugger, I was wondering of any other differences that may potentially be more theoretical in nature.

Comment: @Blam It's not necessarily always that simple... e.g. try this `decimal x = 0.0m; decimal y = 0.00m; Console.Write("{0}, {1}, {2}", x, y, x == y);`

Comment: @Partha I think since OP used the correct term, he understands what the @, just a mystery why it would do anything useful on an empty string

Comment: @DavidG And what does that have to do with @"" versus ""

Comment: @Blam I was suggesting that comparing things in code isn't always as simple as it first seems.

Comment: So are you saying @"" == "" will return a false?

Comment: @Blam No, I'm telling you that comparing things may return true yet in actual fact may be different.

Comment: @DavidG Are you saying @"" and "" are different?

Comment: @Blam Of course not, I'm suggesting that comparing things is not a good way to determine if they are different.

Comment: @DavidG That make absolutely no sense.  You are saying that == is not a valid test if two items are different.  Just how would you test if two items are different?  If you think x and y are different then you have a different definition of different then I or .NET.

Comment: @Blam Look at the example code I gave above. In that the items are different yet `==` returns `true`.

Comment: @DavidG If you think x and y are different that is your problem

Comment: @Blam They ARE different though. Look at the result of `decimal.GetBits()` for both of them. Just because you can't see the difference doesn't mean it isn't there.

Comment: @DavidG Maybe to you they are different.  To me, .NET ==, and .NET CompareTo x and y are not different.   And if the bit representation in SQL was different it would not make them different (to me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following:

```
string a = @"";
string b = "";
```

Generates this IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldstr       ""
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0007:  ldstr       ""
IL_000C:  stloc.1     // b
```

So no, there is no difference.

Answer (score 10):

> This string is used in a regex expression

Regular expressions make heavy use of the `\` character. For example, the following is a regular expression to match precentages from `0` to `100` that always have four decimal places:

```
^(100\.0000|[1-9]?\d\.\d{4})$
```

Because `\` has to be escaped in the more common C# syntax to `\\` the `@""` form allows for the regex to be more easily read, compare:

```
"^(100\\.0000|[1-9]?\\d\\.\\d{4})$"
@"^(100\.0000|[1-9]?\d\.\d{4})$"
```

And for this reason people often get into the habit of using the `@""` form when they are using regular expressions, even in cases where it makes no difference. For one thing, if they later change to something where it does make a difference the only need to change the expression, not the code for the string itself.

I would suggest that this is likely why your colleague used `@""` rather than `""` in this particular case. The .NET produced is the same, but they are used to using `@""` with regular expressions.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the [MSDN documention for string literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx). For an empty string, it has no effect, however it changes the behavior of certain character escape sequences as well as newline handling. Examples taken from the MSDN site:

```
string a = "hello, world";                  // hello, world
string b = @"hello, world";               // hello, world
string c = "hello \t world";               // hello     world
string d = @"hello \t world";               // hello \t world
string e = "Joe said \"Hello\" to me";      // Joe said "Hello" to me
string f = @"Joe said ""Hello"" to me";   // Joe said "Hello" to me
string g = "\\\\server\\share\\file.txt";   // \\server\share\file.txt
string h = @"\\server\share\file.txt";      // \\server\share\file.txt
string i = "one\r\ntwo\r\nthree";
string j = @"one
two
three";
```